# Ubuntu 20.04 on VMWare Workstation 16 says the disk full even though it isn't

Tags: 20.04, vmware, disk, disk-usage, vmware-workstation

I've checked for similar problems more or less but couldn't find the exact cause. I'm in a hurry right now, I'm developing a program on Ubuntu 20.04. If I close this VM for now it won't boot again.

The problem is:

Ubuntu warns me about disk space. I've allocated 60 GB for it. I don't have any documents or applications that would fill the disk. So definitely no I haven't used all of the space that I've allocated.

**Here Ubuntu Disk Status:**
[image]

**Here the VM settings about disk:**

[image]

What would cause this?

Answer (score 0):

I've used the "du" utility to see the large files.

**The disk usage on a specific path:**

[image]

It turned out a single test file that I've deleted were containing 49 GB's of data. I recently copied this file from Windows. Actually, the file size is around 4 KB. I don't know why this has happened. I removed that file and I'm okay right now.

So when copying data from Windows be careful, this also may happen to you.